# PDO not binding placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to change my log in script from *mysql* to *PDO*.
For the rest of my script all seams to be going well apart from this parts and I simply cant see why.

I have the below code

```
...
$pasword=md5($_POST['password']);
$email=$_POST['email'];

....

$query ="SELECT id FROM guests WHERE email=':eml' AND password =':pwd' AND lead_guest=17";
// $param2=array(':eml'=>$email,':pwd'=>$pasword);
$state=$dbh->prepare($query);
$state->bindParam(':eml',$email);
$state->bindParam(':pwd',$pasword);
$state->execute();
```

in it's current state it will return a row count of 0 (which it should not), I have also tried

```
  //$state->bindParam(':eml',$email);
  //$state->bindParam(':pwd',$pasword);
  $state->execute($param2);
```

which also returns a row count of 0.

The variables `$email` and `$pasword` are correct when I `echo` them out, and the script works perfectly using `mysql_` functions.

The `$dbh` variable is in created in a header and with a `$query ="select id where 1"` it works as expected.

I am sure (although could be wrong ) that I have the problem narrowed down to the `state->bindParam()` part of the script. I am completely lost why this part of the script is not working any advice warmly welcome.

Comment: Only hashing a password with MD5 is not enough; use a [strong password hashing algorithm](http://php.net/password).

Comment: Hey at least  questions with PHP prepared statements start to appear more often on stackoverflow,or its just my impression.

Comment: @Mihai I see SQL injection vulnerabilities still every day, even every hour.

Comment: I thought that pdo was supposed to protect against sql injections?

Comment: I dont think he was referring  to your code.

Comment: @MarkGilchrist - PDO helps you write code that protects against SQL injection; if someone's writing poor SQL, it doesn't matter what library they're using. Your code is fine - it's people who use PDO and still concatenate variables direct from $_POST directly in there who are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove *single quotes* `'` :

```
SELECT id FROM guests WHERE email=:eml AND password =:pwd
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query will be

```
$query ="SELECT id FROM guests WHERE email=:eml AND password =:pwd AND lead_guest=17";
```

No single quotes around `:eml` and `:pwd`.